# Finding max in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I am looking to apply max function in Oracle SQL on the below example.

```
CN     10
EX     10
FW     10
CN     11
EX     11
FW     11
```

I want the result as below.

```
CN     11
EX     11
FW     11
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Do you want the maximum for each value in the first column?  Or do you want all rows where the second column is the maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of fetching max as follows:

- `MAX` aggregate function:

  ```
  select col1, max(col2) as max_col2
    from your_table
  group by col1
  ```
- Using `analytical function`:

  ```
  select * from
  (select t.*, 
          row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc nulls last) as rn
    from your_table)
  where rn = 1
  ```
- Using `NOT EXISTS`

  ```
  select t.*
    from your_table t
   where not exists 
         (select 1 from your_table tt
           where tt.col1 = t.col1 
             and tt.col2 > t.col2)
  ```

Comment: Partition method worked excellent! Thank you Tejash!

Answer (score 1):

Use `max()` with `group by`

```
select col1,max(col2)
from tablename
group by col1
```